# How to insert null value in JSON type in golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

i have create remote schema for some purpose i have to insert a json value like this

```
"convert_to_money": {"IDR":10000},
```

i create a mutation field like this

```
"convert_to_money": {
 Type: scalar.JSON,
},
```

resolver like this :

```
Convert_to_money := p.Args["convert_to_money"].(map[string]interface{})
```

struct like this :

```
type TimeOvertimePolicy struct {
    ConvertToMoney          JSONB
}
```

and handler like this :

```
func UpdateOvertimesPolicy(Convert_to_money model.JSONB) (res gqltypes.SuccessType, err error) {
  timeOvertimesPolicy := model.TimeOvertimePolicy{
        ConvertToMoney:         Convert_to_money,
    }

  err = pg.DB.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    d := tx.Create(&timeOvertimesPolicy)
  }
}
```

How can i do input null value for case like this?

Which is running now I have to insert a variable `"convert_to_money": {}` like this if the variable is null

I wish i can insert variable like this if null

```
"convert_to_money": null
```

Answer (score 1):

In `go` `nil` (null) exist for pointers. So if you want to insert a `nil` value then your `Convert_to_money` should be of a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert vairable like this

```
"convert_to_money": nil
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gorm, you can use pgtype.JSONB to init a "null" value:

> pgtype.JSONB{Status: pgtype.Null}